# Java Sampling Rate Conversion

Tags: java, audio, wav

In my Java code, I would like to convert a WAV file of 44100 Hz to a WAV file of 8000 Hz. I know that I have to low-pass filter and then decimate (+interpolate) (the DSP theory) but I do not want to implement it from scratch.

I am looking for a library that can efficiently do it. Do you know any?

I am able to read wav files into a buffer and also write wav files from buffer to file if it will make it easier.

Comment: i need to convert wav file with 22khz to 8khz, please help me if you have implemented this yourself.

Comment: @Reneez, please start a new question and people like me might help you there. You can send me the link to your question here.

Comment: I have posted new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929478/downsampling-pcm-wav-audio-from-22khz-to-8khz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/index.php). It provides a [wrapper for ffmpeg](http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php) which can handle all sorts of conversion work (including audio resampling) very efficiently.

Comment: In the end, I implemented it myself with the help of MATLAB to get the filter coefficients. I accepted the only answer that shows effort and might be useful in the future for others. Thank you.