# Downsampling pcm/wav audio from 22khz to 8khz

Tags: android, pcm, downsampling

My android application needs to convert PCM(22khz) to AMR , but the API [AmrInputStream](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/AmrInputStream.java) only supports with **pcm of 8khz**.

How can i **downsample** the **pcm from 22 khz to 8 khz?**

Answer (score 1):

The sample rate is hard coded in AmrInputStream.java.

```
// frame is 20 msec at 8.000 khz
private final static int SAMPLES_PER_FRAME = 8000 * 20 / 1000;
```

So you have to convert the PCM to AMR first.

```
InputStream inStream;
inStream = new FileInputStream(wavFilename);
AmrInputStream aStream = new AmrInputStream(inStream);

File file = new File(amrFilename);        
file.createNewFile();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); 

//adding tag #!AMR\n
out.write(0x23);
out.write(0x21);
out.write(0x41);
out.write(0x4D);
out.write(0x52);
out.write(0x0A);    

byte[] x = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len=aStream.read(x)) > 0) {
    out.write(x,0,len);
}

out.close();
```

For Downsampling, You can try [the Mary API](http://mary.dfki.de/javadoc/4.0.0/marytts/util/data/audio/AudioConverterUtils.html#downSampling%28javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream,%20int%29).

Comment: i have done this already, what i want to do is downsample the pcm before converting to amr.

Comment: Find a [mary api](http://elckerlyc.ewi.utwente.nl/browser/Elckerlyc/Shared/repository/MARYTTS/java/marytts/util/data/audio/AudioConverterUtils.java) to downsample audio file.

Comment: this api doesn't run on android. :(

Comment: Yes, but I'm pretty sure there is no other API in Android that can downsample an audio file unless you implement one or use an existing library.

Comment: do you know any implementation of downsampling in c or c++?

Comment: Yeah, [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/resample/Free_Resampling_Software.html) you are, and [this link](http://tdistler.com/2010/07/22/audio-resampling-using-ffmpeg-avcodec) contains a guide to use ffmpeg. But do you want to use native code to do this in Android?

Comment: Androd allow you to use native library. see [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I find a java downsample lib :https://github.com/hutm/JSSRC
there is also a c version could be used by jni